# Dispersion operators

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

[image]

Remark: Where $e^{(j)}\in \mathbb{R}^k$ is the standard basis.

This is from the book, "The Coordinate Free Approach to Linear Models", by Michael Wichura. I don't quite understand what he means by "taking the value $e^j$ with probability $p_j$. Does he mean that $E(X_j)=p_j$ or what?

**EDIT**: I still have some questions. How do we show that the dispersion operator is projection onto the orthogonal complement of r? The only information I know is that $E(X)=0$ and $E(X_i)=p_i$.I tried computing it but I didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is meant that the probability that $X=e^{(j)}$ is $p_j$.
The only possible values of $X$ are the basis vectors.
The fact that the probabilities add to one supports this interpretation; there is no probability left for other values.

The expected value of $Y$ should be computed component by component.
The value of $X_j$ is either one (probability $p_j$) or zero (probability $1-p_j$).
The possible values of $Y_j$ (with corresponding probabilities) can be computed from the formula for $Y_j$.
A quick calculation, which I leave as an exercise, shows that the expected value of $Y_j$ is indeed zero.

Comment: If that's the case then I don't see why $E(Y)=0$.

Comment: @thegamer The expected value of $X$ is non-zero, but that of $Y$ indeed seems to be zero. Just compute the expected value of each component $Y_j$ separately; $X_j$ is either one (with probability $p_j$) or zero (otherwise).

Comment: Ah okay. Got it thanks.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for computing the dispersion operator. I tried using the information given but I tap getting the wrong values.

Comment: @thegamer I updated my answer to contain my previous comment. I'm not familiar with dispersion operators. I strongly recommend asking the follow-up question(s) in a separate question. I gave you an answer to your original question and a little more, but I'm not going to expand the answer corresponding to your edit (due to lack of time and knowledge).

Comment: Okay thanks Joonas.